# android Alarm Manager Service Kernel time zone update to

Tags: android, timezone, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

has anyone noticed that when time passes from 23:59 to 00:00 which is a new day, emulator shows a message like:

```
08-06 00:00:00.092: DEBUG/AlarmManagerService(52): Kernel timezone updated to -180 minutes west of GMT
```

may it mean that there is a broadcast in the system fired at just after the day chaged?
And i wonder, can it be possible to put a broadcastreceiver called with this notification so i can manage my activity or some other components of my application freely knowing that date has just changed?

Comment: It is happening many times a minute for me, not just at the change of the day (local time?)

Comment: It is happening many times a minute for me ONLY if automatic timezone adjustment based on mobile network is enabled.